# How to move to next tab (or navigate to another tab) on the click of a QPushButton?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qpushbutton, qtabwidget

To be more precise, I'm looking for a way to assign a function to a button to shift to another tab on the click of a button.

I've been looking everywhere for the python code and majority of them have posted its c++ code, its no where to be found

I was able to found a c++ code snippet of what i wanted to do, but had absolutely no idea what its python translation would be

following is the c++ code:

```
ui->tabWidget->setCurrentWidget(ui->tab);
```

and i have absolutely no idea what this means, all what I want is a PushButton, on click, would move to the next tab. Kindly help

Maybe this link could help understand my query better

https://forum.qt.io/topic/56408/solved-how-to-open-specific-tab-on-pushbutton-clicked-in-tabwidget/2

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the current tab index to the index of target tab and then reset the layout in order to update the main screen.

```
def next_Tab(self):
    self.setCurrentIndex(1)
    self.setLayout(layout)
```